# What are general Theorems / Conjectures for Graph Characterization other than of Forbidden subgraphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Recently, I have been interested in graph characterization problems. One such problem deals with forbidden subgraphs or minors. Robert and Seymour long back in a series of papers (Graph Minors Series) proved theorem related to graph minors now called 'Robert-Seymour' theorem. There are conjectures I found related to $K_6$ and $K_7$ minors (Topics in Chromatic Graph Theory) and more general ones like Hadwiger conjecture.

So are there in literature - theorems/conjectures or similar to aforementioned some undertaking that deal with graph characterization other than forbidden subgraphs? Wherein the characterization simply does not deal with "subgraph related" problems.

In short, I am looking for more characterization problems that are as general as or more general than Robertson–Seymour theorem in graph theory literature but not about forbidden subgraphs.

Comment: The characterization of bipartite graphs as graphs having no odd cycles is *absolutely* a forbidden-subgraph characterization!

Comment: Okay yes. I couldn't find a simple example. There might be. @Misha Lavrov But the problem remains.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a bright line that says what is or isn't a "characterization problem". For example, a graph is $2$-connected if and only if it has a (proper) [ear decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_decomposition). Would you call this a characterization of 2-connected graphs?

Comment: Apparently I sought an analogous statement to Robert-Seymour Theorem about a family of graphs that can also be defined using some finite set of structures/properties. How about say "characterization via decomposition"? In that case, a statement about a family of graphs that can be defined using a finite set of graph decompositions or, in your case, using a finite set of graph-connectedness properties.

Comment: In this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895623000862), titled **Induced subgraphs and tree decompositions - II,** says it is motivated by "what are the unavoidable induced subgraphs of graphs with large treewidth?" _(I haven't read the paper - just the abstract)_ But speaking of tree-width... Graphs of treewidth at most 3 are characterized by four forbidden minors ($K_5$, the graph of the octahedron, the graph of the pentagonal prism, and
the Wagner graph). When $k=1$, it's 3-vertex cycle graph. When $k=2$, it's $K_4$.

Comment: There are a few more papers in this sequence of work, and the project is still ongoing. Indeed, they investigate obstructions in terms of induced subgraphs to treewidth.